# okhttp3 + retrofit handle etag with Marvel api

Tags: okhttp, etag

Since the [Marvel api](http://developer.marvel.com/documentation/generalinfo) 
must pass hash and time stamp as parameters, then the url actually will change at every request. Just like this: https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?apikey=xxxxx&hash=xxxxx&ts=xxxx

And Okhttp's cache will work based on the same url, otherwise etag won't be useful.

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to bring it up with the API’s designers and explain why it’s cache-hostile. Browsers won’t cache these successfully, for example.

Once you’ve done that, you can use a [network interceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors) to add the cache-breaking query parameters to your outbound requests. That way requests that don’t need the network have cacheable URLs.

Comment: I agree, although it's an open api. But I do have seen a few this kind of design. Like, adding requestId as a parameter which is for log tracing, it's not unusual.  How to deal with them? Add them all to header or just no cache that way?  Please do tell if you have better idea.